# WPF KeyGestures - Binding non alphanumeric keys

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

Should be a simple one, but I can't work out how to do it. Using WPF4 I want to Bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to Zoom Out and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to Zoom In:

```
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Content.ZoomInCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+="/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Content.ZoomOutCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+-"/>
```

However, I'm getting errors: in the case of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>:

> Requested value '=' was not found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay - it turns out that the <kbd>=</kbd> key does not exist (you can check this through the `Key`-enumeration - there is no entry for *Equal* or *EqualSign*)... I use an international keyboard, so you have to find which key sequence you hit to enter <kbd>=</kbd> (for me it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D0</kbd> on a danish keyboard) - and use that key-sequence.

So your XAML should be (in Denmark):

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding Content.ZoomInCommand}" Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+D0"/>
```

EDIT: I believe on an American system it is the `OemPlus` key - but you can check it by console-writeline'ing the `e.Key` argument in a key-down event handler)

EDIT2: the <kbd>-</kbd> key is `OemMinus` on my system.

Comment: And I hope you are not going to internationalize your application... :-)

Comment: Thanks! Looking in the keydown event was the way to go. What I was looking for was "Ctrl+OemPlus" & "Ctrl+OemMinus". I'll worry about internationalization later!

Comment: +1 for " you can check it by console-writeline'ing the e.Key argument in a key-down event handler" for me it was Key="Add"

Answer (score 8):

Hint for Users with a **German keyboard** (maybe some other countries as well):

The numpad keys "+" and "-" are "Add" and "Subtract"

The normal keys "+" and "-" are "OemPlus" and "OemMinus"

So

```
<KeyBinding Gesture = "OemPlus" Command="myCommand" />
```

will fire the command if you press "+" on the main keyboard.