# Reference the '=' key in my WPF XAML key binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, input, keyboard

In Windows WPF XAML, I need to reference the `=` key for my keyboard shortcut, but cannot see it anywhere in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key(v=vs.110).aspx).

The key combo I'm going for is Control and the "plus/equals" key. The `=` symbol is the default character when key is pressed alone. A `+` symbol is typed if I'm holding down shift. I will not be holding down shift. I will simply be holding down 'CTRL' and pressing the `=` key.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding FontSizeUp}" Gesture="CTRL+=" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding FontSizeDown}" Gesture="CTRL+-" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366424/wpf-keygestures-binding-non-alphanumeric-keys).

Comment: @Ruben Yeah that's totally it. Create an answer and I'll make it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>=</kbd> key is `OemPlus` Key enumeration value.
<kbd>_</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> key is `OemMinus` Key enumeration value.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding FontSizeUp}" Gesture="CTRL+OemPlus" />
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding FontSizeDown}" Gesture="CTRL+OemMinus" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```